# GridView Pops out NullPointerException

Tags: android, gridview, nullpointerexception

[The rows are coming in reverse order. It should be Monday then Tuesday then Wednesday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eejl.png)I have a gridview which dynamically fetches data of current week(i.e monday to today). I am facing two issues. 
1) My gridView elements are not arranged properly.
2) GridView shows data of that day also whose data does not exists. It simply copies all previous row values. I know rearrangement problem is because of resetPosition variable not getting updated. but if i update it, i get NullPointerException. How can i get rid of these problems?

```
public class ViewTimeTable extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> mondayStrength,tuesdayStrength,wednesdayStrength,thursdayStrength,fridayStrength;
    String [] currentWeek;
    int resetPosition;
    private Date date;
    private Map map;
    private int position,pos;
    private TextView classTextView,sectionTextView,dateTextView;
    private String Class,section,today,day;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.one_day_layout);
    classTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.class_textView);
    sectionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.section_textView);
    dateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date_textView);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);
    mondayStrength = new ArrayList<String>();
    tuesdayStrength = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    map = new HashMap();

    String[] lectureTimings = {"Lec/Day","I","II","III","IV","V","VI"};

    for(int i =0;i<lectureTimings.length;i++){
        mondayStrength.add(lectureTimings[i]);
        pos = i;
    }
    System.out.println(position);
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Lectures");

    GridView mondayRow = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.mon_grid_view);
    final GridAdapterChirag mondayAdapter = new GridAdapterChirag(ViewTimeTable.this,R.layout.grid_element, mondayStrength);
    mondayRow.setAdapter(mondayAdapter);


    System.out.println(position);
    currentWeek = getThisWeek();
    Class = intent.getStringExtra("Class");
    section = intent.getStringExtra("Section");
    position = pos+1;
    System.out.println(position);
    classTextView.append(Class);
    sectionTextView.append(section);
resetPosition=position;
    String [] day = {"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"};
    for(int i=0;i<currentWeek.length;i++) {
        mondayStrength.add(position, day[i]);

        System.out.print("ResetPosition before loop"+resetPosition);
        query.whereEqualTo("Date", currentWeek[i]);
        try {
            List<ParseObject> objects = query.find();
            for (ParseObject object : objects) {

                String lid = object.getString("LectureID");
                if (lid.substring(7, 9).equals(Class)) {

                    String m = String.valueOf(lid.charAt(10));
                    if (m.equals(section)) {
                        String periodNumber = lid.substring(4, 6);
                        if (periodNumber.equals("01"))
                            position += 1;
                        else if (periodNumber.equals("02"))
                            position += 2;
                        else if (periodNumber.equals("03"))
                            position += 3;
                        else if (periodNumber.equals("04"))
                            position += 4;
                        else if (periodNumber.equals("05"))
                            position += 5;
                        else if (periodNumber.equals("06"))
                            position += 6;
                        else
                            position = 100;

                        map.put(position, object.getString("Strength"));
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("ResetPosition"+resetPosition);
                System.out.println("Position"+position);
                position = resetPosition;
            }
            System.out.println(map);

           for (int k = 1; k <= map.size(); k++) {
                mondayStrength.add(resetPosition + k, map.get(resetPosition+k).toString());
            }resetPosition+=7;

            System.out.println(mondayStrength.size());
            //position++;
            //mondayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

//This method simply returns array of dates of current week

```
private String[] getThisWeek() {
    int factor;
    ArrayList<String> week = new ArrayList<>();
    long oneDay = 86400000;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long todayInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    String date;

    String todaysDay = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE").format(new Date());
    if(todaysDay.equals("Mon"))
        factor = 0;
    else if(todaysDay.equals("Tue"))
        factor = 1;
    else if(todaysDay.equals("Wed"))
        factor = 2;
    else if(todaysDay.equals("Thu"))
        factor = 3;
    else if(todaysDay.equals("Fri"))
        factor = 4;
    else if(todaysDay.equals("Sat"))
        factor = 5;
    else
        factor = 6;

    for(;factor>=0;factor--){
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(todayInMillis-factor*oneDay);
        Date d = new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(d);
        week.add(date);
    }
    String [] runningWeek = new String[week.size()];
    runningWeek = week.toArray(runningWeek);

    return runningWeek;
}
```

LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tonystark.adminlogin/com.example.tonystark.adminlogin.ViewTimeTable}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                      at com.example.tonystark.adminlogin.ViewTimeTable.onCreate(ViewTimeTable.java:126)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post logcat error trash here.

Comment: what is `line 126` in your java code.

Comment: line 126: mondayStrength.add(resetPosition + k, map.get(resetPosition+k).toString());

Comment: the error is that line check the value `resetPosition` and `map.get(resetPosition+k).toString()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I have already checked them. They return correct values in current iteration. But still the error persists.

Comment: Already Checked the link What is a Null Pointer Exception